# Using Java 8 streams how do I convert Map<String, List<Something>> to Map<String, Integer>?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

So, I want to make a new map from the old one. In the new `Map<String, Integer>` the String key denotes the same key as in the first map and the Integer value denotes the size of the corresponding `List<Something>`. I want to make the transformation using Java 8 streams. I tried something like, but it gives me errors.

```
Map<String, List<Something>> map1=.....
Map<String, Integer> map2;
map2=map1.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(p-> p.getKey(), p->getValue().size()));
```

Comment: `p->getValue().size()` does not compile. I guess you expected `p-> p.getValue().size()`

Comment: yes, sorry for the typo. Corrected.

Comment: now it works. I did not see this mistake in code :(

Comment: Now your question contains valid code which probably invalidates posted answer. Don't remove described problem from your question. Instead provide error messages you ware getting.

Comment: Consider removing the question since it does not provide any value to other Stack Overflow users.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak OP can't remove question which has positively scored answer(s). Also I wouldn't say it doesn't provide any value for SO. It may be off-topic but those terms are not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It missing `p` before `getValue()`

```
map2 = map1.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue().size()));
```

Comment: yes, this was the mistake :( I didn't see it. I will approve your answer in 5 minutes....

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
Map<String,Long> map2 = map1.entrySet().stream()
                           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p->p.getKey(),
                                      Collectors.counting()));
```

if you don't mind a `Map<String,Long>` instead of `Map<String,Integer>`.